# Define a Factory on model with hyphens in field names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, factory-bot

I am trying to create a factory on a model with field names that contain hyphens and I cannot figure out syntax that will allow the hyphens.  I am using Mongoid.

```rb
#model.rb
class MyModel
    include Mongoid::Document

    field :field1
    field :"data-field2"
    field :"data-field3"
end



#factories/my_model.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :my_model do
    field1 'some text'
    data-field2 'some_element_classname'
    data-field2 'some_other_element_classname'
  end
end
```

I get this error

```
unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '(' (SyntaxError)
```

Anyone know how to get around this?

Comment: can you try using `send`? i.e., `send "data-field2" 'some_element_classname'`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`FactoryGirl::DefinitionProxy`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/lib/factory_girl/definition_proxy.rb) defines `method_missing` to call `add_attribute` using the missing method's name, so you should be able to sub that in instead:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :my_model do
    field1 'some text'
    add_attribute(:"data-field2", 'some_element_classname')
    add_attribute(:"data-field3") { # add_attribute with block }
  end
end
```